# What is the derivative of $\int^{x^2}_1 t^2+t+1\ dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given this problem and told to find it's derivative: $$f(x)=\int^{x^2}_1 t^2+t+1\ dt$$I thought the derivative was simply the inside function in terms of x - $x^2+x+1$. But, this is not correct. Where am I going wrong? What piece am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

If $h$ is continuous , $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $$F(x)=\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t)\;dt$$ then $F'(x)=h(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)- h(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the chain rule.  Plus you need to evaluate the integrand at $x^2$.

So  $F'(x)=((x^2)^2+x^2+1)2x=2x^5+2x^3+2x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of 
$$
F(t) = \int \left(t^2+t+1\right)dt
$$
then
$$
f(x) = F\left(x^2\right) - F(1),
$$
therefore
$$
f'(x)
 = \frac{d}{dx} F\left(x^2\right)
 = f\left(x^2\right) \frac{d\left[x^2\right]}{dx}
$$

Can you finish this now?